# Como pegar o objeto de resposta de uma requisição ajax com laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Pessoal estou fazendo uma requisição fetch para o laravel sem usar jquery e gostaria de pegar o retorno desta requisição, porém quando dou um `console.log()` no response o console informa undefined.

Esta é a minha requisição:

```
fetch(action, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "X-CSRF-Token": token
        },
        method: "post",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password
        })
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Este é o meu controller que retorna a informação de campo vazio:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if (in_array('', $request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        $json['message'] = "Campo vazio!";
        return response()->json($json);
    }

    var_dump($request->all());
}
```

A requisição obteve sucesso e o brouser informa a mensagem de response:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém o `console.log(data)` retorna `undefined`, como eu posso retornar o objeto que contém a mensagem?

Aproveitando a questão, esta é a melhor maneira de fazer esta request?

Obrigado pessoal

Comment: `var_dump` está errado nesse contexto o correto é `return $request->all();`

Comment: Mas o retorno da mensagem vem através da linha: `return response()->json($json);`. O var_dump eu coloquei apenas para teste. Mesmo que eu o tire ainda não consego ter a mensagem do response no console.

Comment: `console.log(data)` se precisa somente do `data` ele tem a resposta